# Understanding a SQL statement with Join and Groups

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and PHP programming, so I need some help in fully understanding this SQL select statement from someone else code.

```
$sql = "SELECT a.*, b.name as city, c.name as state, c.code as state_code 
FROM hotel a
JOIN city b on a.IDCity = b.IDCity
JOIN state c on b.IDState = c.IDState";
```

This is what I understand (or my guess):

- It's selecting everything from the hotels table.
- It's selecting the names from the city table?
- It's selecting the names from the state table
- It's selecting the code from the state table
- It's joining the names of the city with everything from the hotels table to create a IDCITY?
- It's joining names of state with names of cities to create IDState field.

This is what I don't understand at all:

- How is this select statement grabbing fields from different tables, but it only states "From Hotel a"
- What are the a. b. c. in this code? I'm guessing their groups, but then why is their two c's for name as state and code as state code?
- If the a. b. c. are groups, I'm guessing they also indicate which table to grab info from? How does this even work?

Comment: In order to understand it you have to know how a `JOIN` works. I don't want to go into details how they work, but a really great place to start with is reading this article: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thank you for the article, I will read up on it to understand join statements more. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> . Its selecting everything from the hotels table:

Not completely true, it's selecting every **column** from the hotels table (not necessarily every **row**)

> . Its selecting the names from the city table?

Correct

> . Its selecting the names from the state table

Correct

> . Its selecting the code from the state table

Correct

> . Its joining the names of the city with everything from the hotels
>   table to create a IDCITY? . Its joining names of state with names of
>   cities to create IDState field...

The table `Hotels` has a column named `IdCity` that identifies the city of that hotel. So you are using that column from that table to join with the `City` table, which also has an `IdCity` column (presumably the key of that table). This join is an `INNER JOIN`, so only rows from the table `Hotels` that has an `IdCity` that corresponds to an existing `IdCity` from the `City` table will be returned. Then that result is joined in the same way to the `State` table (in this case using the common column `IdState` that exists in the `City` and `State` table).

> .How is this select statement grabbing fields from different tables,
>   but it only states "From Hotel a"

It's not, that's what the `JOIN`s are doing, relating the tables using common columns to obtain data from those tables.

> .What are the a. b. c. in this code? I'm guessing their groups, but
>   then why is their two c's for name as state and code as state code?

Those are table aliases. You use them for readability and clarity. You are saying that the `Hotels` table will be called `a`, the `City` table will be called `b` and the `State` table will be called `c`. Then you are using those as a prefix when using your columns, so `b.name` means `the column name from the City table`. The `as something` is renaming the column in your `SELECT`, so `c.name as state` means that your resulting set will call that colum `state`.

> .If the a. b. c. are groups, I'm guessing they also indicate which
>   table to grab info from? How does this even work?

They are not, as I said in the previous bullet point, they are table aliases.

Answer (score 2):

> How is this select statement grabbing fields from different tables, but it only states "From Hotel a"

from hotel a, means that the base information is pulled from hotel tables, which is now aliased to "a" so the table called hotel is also called "a" now

> What are the a. b. c. in this code? I'm guessing their groups, but then why is their two c's for name as state and code as state code?

the base table hotel and its data is now augmented with two tables, table city which is called b and table state which is now named c

```
JOIN city b on a.IDCity = b.IDCity
JOIN state c on b.IDState = c.IDState";
```

c.name is actually table "c" column name. the table state is alias as "c"

> If the a. b. c. are groups, I'm guessing they also indicate which table to grab info from? How does this even work?

the table has rows, which lets say there is 1 row with 5 fields (aka columns) you can add a 6th column if you know some data indirectly in another table. if we know you have a car, and we know that all cars have a steering wheel, we can indirectly say that you have a wheel

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. It really helped me understand this much better.!

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM hotel a
```

Grab all rows from the `hotel` table and use `a` as shorthand to refer to these rows.

```
JOIN city b on a.IDCity = b.IDCity
```

Return all possible combinations of rows in `a` and the `city` table, and use `b` as shorthand for the columns that were originally in the `city` table.  Then filter the result and keep rows where the condition `on a.IDCity = b.IDCity` is true.  In other words, keep rows where the `IDCity` column from `a` matches the `IDCity` column from `b`.

```
JOIN state c on b.IDState = c.IDState
```

For each row that results from joining `a` and `b`, return all rows from `state` with the matching `IDState`, and call those rows `c`.

As an exercise, replace `on a.IDCity = b.IDCity` with `on 1=1` and explain the result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I'm basically changing his code around to grab locations for cities. But this helped me out a lot. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The query is selecting every column from `Hotels`.  The `a` is an alias, used as a pointer to represent `Hotels` in your code.  This is entirely optional.  If aliases weren't used the join would be `ON HOTELS.IDCITY=CITY.IDCITY` etc.

Records in the Hotels table will have a field called `IDCity`.  That ID matches to a corresponding ID in the `City` table called `IDCity`.  `b` on the `City` table is also an alias.

The use of "JOIN" is by default an INNER JOIN (in SQL Server), which means only return where BOTH tables have a match.  If the Hotel record doesn't have an IDCity (its NULL), you won't see it in your result set.

From there you "JOIN" to the `State` table `c` (again, c is just an alias).  The join is done on the field `IDState`, back to the `IDState` for each city.

Again, since it's a "JOIN" it only returns where both tables have a match... so in this query, all 3 tables must have a matching referential ID value.

So this query is not "creating" the ID's, they are referential pointers from one table to another.

The ID's are referred to as a Primary Key (`IDCity` is the Primary Key on `City`) and a Foreign Key (`IDCity` in `Hotels` is a Foreign Key).

Example: The "Hilton Hotel" in the Hotel table has an `IDCity` of 7, and in the `City` table `IDCity` 7 has a corresponding name of "Las Vegas".  The `City` table for 7/Las Vegas would have an `IDState` of 12 and in the `State` table, `IDState` 12 has a name of "Nevada".

This lets you assign a city/state value to every hotel, without writing "LAS VEGAS" and "NEVADA" for 200 hotels, you just give it an `IDCity` of 7.  The city name and state name are known via the references to the underlying tables.

Not writing the same value over and over is integral to SQL performance, and database normalization.

Answer (score 1):

The a, b, and c names found in this code are "aliases". Aliases are a way of referring to a table in the FROM segment of an SQL statement. In your case, the FROM portion looks like this:

```
FROM hotel a
JOIN city b on a.IDCity = b.IDCity
JOIN state c on b.IDState = c.IDState
```

Thus, a is the "alias" assigned to hotel, b is assigned to city, and c is assigned to state. The JOINS show which fields are connected, in this case the fields IDCity are connecting hotel and city, and the fields IDState are connecting city and state.

Since that SQL statement is parsed as a unit, the SELECT portion knows which table each alias refers to with the FROM statement. So, in your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT a.*, b.name as city, c.name as state, c.code as state_code
```

Since a refers to hotel, it is choosing everything from hotel. Since b refers to City, it is choosing city.name, but the field will be called "city" in the result set. Since c refers to the table state, the SELECT is also pulling state.name and state.code, but the fields will be called "state" and "state_code" in your result set.

The major thing to understand is that the a, b, and c are essentially nicknames that person who wrote the query gave to the tables to make organization and redundant typing easier. Aliases are used for other reasons in more complex queries, but this overview will serve the purpose of understanding how this query executes rather well.